# add column to tabular by overlay, but already reserve its space

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays

I want to add the column `b` to my table and it should look like in my first tabular. Except from the point, that the column `a` should *not* be completely centered. (The column `a` should not jump to the left, when slide two is shown)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
a \only<2>{& b}\\
\hline
1 \only<2>{& 2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
a \visible<2>{& b}\\
\hline
1 \visible<2>{& 2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
a & \visible<2>{b}\\
\hline
1 & \visible<2>{2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the most elegant solution, but you could enclose the whole `tabular` in a `parbox` of appropriate width.

Comment: @leandriis I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to add an `\hspace` on the first overlay only. You can either guess the required with or, a bit more work, measure the width of a table that includes the widest entry of your second column.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\mywidth}
\settowidth{\mywidth}{%
\begin{tabular}{|>{$}{c}<{$}|}%
2
\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{$}{c}<{$}}|}
\hline
a \only<2>{& b}\\
\hline
1 \only<2>{& 2}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\only<1>{\hspace*{\mywidth}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm unsure, if this is always practical, but I does here it's enough :)

Comment: Somehow you guessed `x` and by that it the right width is reserved. If you replace `x` by `b\\2` the table still moves a little bit

Comment: @Ben You'll have to put the widest label of the second column in place for `x`.

Comment: The widest label is `b` or `2` isn't it?

Comment: @Ben yes, you are correct. A `|` was missing.

Comment: I could have seen that...